# How to select all records where ANY two columns are above a certain value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with 50 columns. Looks like this

```
GUID  Field1  Field2  Field3 .... Field50
----  ------  ------  ------      -------
1     0       1       0           0
2     1       0       0           1
3     0       2       3           1
```

I need to find all records where **any** two (or more) of the 50 columns are > 0. This would result in records 2 and 3 being returned.

I'm not really sure how to tackle this. If I were to try and test all the permutations it would be insane. There's got to be a better way.

I'm using SQL.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the wrong database design.  When you have the same data in multiple columns -- only distinguished by a numerical suffix -- then that usually suggests that you really want a proper junction table.

In any case, you can do this, it is just a long `case`-based condition:

```
select t.*
from t
where ((case when field1 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) + 
       (case when field2 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) + 
       . . .
       (case when field50 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) + 
      ) >= 2;
```

You need to fill in the `. . .` with the additional 47 fields.

Comment: My field names aren't actually field1 field2 i just used that in the example